# Close an open file via Windows.h function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

How to close an open file in Windows if I know its name, for example "C:\1.txt" (it is opened vis CreateFile(...))? Thanks

Comment: If you don't own the handle to the file, you must somehow notify the owner that the file has been closed. In general it is not a good philosophy to close a file which you do not own (e.g. have a handle to).

Answer (score 0):

Just [close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the handle that was created when you made a call to CreateFile. `CloseHandle()`

BTW, why use windows API when you have C++ standard methods to handle files?

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/39236/)

Comment: Perhaps he needs to use that handle for something OS specific. You can not just generalise a recommendation for C standard library functions over OS APIs.