# How to close particular aplication after opening it in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

So in my code I'm opening for example notepad using ShellExecute and I want to close it after but I cannot find any working way, so my question is, what is the easiest way to close particular aplication using c++ code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{

    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "notepad", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

    Sleep(10000);

    //here I'm missing the part that closes previously opened notepad

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use `ShellExecuteEx` or `CreateProcess` so that you get the handle of the newly launched process. Then see [Using CreateProcess() and exit/close the opened Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081028/using-createprocess-and-exit-close-the-opened-application).

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question to this post;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972410/close-an-open-file-via-windows-h-function

Comment: @adarian No, it's not a duplicate of that. That post is about closing a file handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) with [`SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow#members), then you can pass it as a parameter it to the [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) function.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo{};
    lpExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    lpExecInfo.lpFile = L"notepad.exe";
    lpExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    lpExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    lpExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
    lpExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
    lpExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    lpExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ShellExecuteEx(&lpExecInfo);

    Sleep(3000);
    if (lpExecInfo.hProcess)
    {
        TerminateProcess(lpExecInfo.hProcess, 0);
        CloseHandle(lpExecInfo.hProcess);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does mean 'L' in this line of code ` lpExecInfo.lpFile = L"notepad.exe"; `? When I use whole code, it shows that i cannot assign const wchar_t to LPCSTR, when I delete this 'L' i can run program without any error but it doesn't close my notepad then

Comment: @Arrow25 Because I call UNICODE's api `ShellExecuteExW` and maybe your default is `ShellExecuteExA`, of course, I recommend you to use the UNICDE version. The program can close Notepad normally here, I suggest you rebuild the program and try it.

Comment: So if I'm thinking correctly I need to change my encoding type to unicode in ide in order this to work properly?

Comment: @Arrow25 No, it has nothing to do with which version of the API you call. Have you checked that `lpExecInfo.hProcess` is empty? And if the `TerminateProcess` function returns TRUE.

Comment: Oh okay, I fixed my problem, I didn't know you are calling notepad too, I thought this whole code is just for closing it and I was calling ShellExecute eariler too so i had 2 notepads, sorry I don't know functions used here I need to read about them, after deleting 'L' everything works fine for me how it is thank you, also is 'lpExecInfo{}' like name assigned to SHELLEXECUTEINFO?

Comment: Just initialize the structure.

Comment: Okay, and then it is assigning values to certain 'members' of this structure and what does 'ShellExecuteEx(&lpExecInfo)' function at the end ?

Comment: Call the `ShellExecuteEx` function, just like you call `ShellExecute`, but with different parameters.

Comment: so this function executes lpExecInfo structure right, but why this function is called at the end of lpExecInfo structure ?

Comment: @Arrow25, It initializes all the parameters needed by the `ShellExecuteEx` to a `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure, and then pass the structure to the `ShellExecuteEx`. This function will get the parameters saved in the structure to create the process.